# Exclude JavaScript libraries from Sonar

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

If you look at this site analysing JavaScript with Sonar you see that there are lots of errors reported on the JavaScript libraries.

http://nemo.sonarsource.org/drilldown/violations/jquery?rids%5B%5D=421365&severity=MAJOR

How can I prevent Sonar reporting the errors in the JavaScript libraries that I am using (since I can't fix any issues)?

At the same time, if I do manage to exclude the library, I don't want errors like "undefined variables" to appear in my files because they are referencing the JavaScript library.

If it makes any difference, I am using ExtJS 4.0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am using Maven and ExtJS 4.1 in my project. I have managed to run the analysis only on my source code by putting these lines in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
    <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
    <sonar.exclusions>extjs/**</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

I don't know whether you're using Maven as well, but perhaps this will give you some hints.

Answer (score 31):

You can add the library as a source file exclusion inside of *Analysis Scope* configuration, and you should use some willcards to help you.

[image]

Answer (score -7):

Often you can hide your JavaScript from other interpreters using a cdata wrapper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*//*---->*/

alert('Your Javascript is working!');

/*--*//*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the JS library that I am using. I am really looking for config in Sonar to do this. Probably via the build mechanism somehow.